# Unable to debug plugin in NopCommerce

Tags: asp.net-mvc, debugging, visual-studio-2013, nopcommerce

I am working on creating a plugin for the open source webshop NopCommerce 3.2. However, I have a problem debugging a view file in that plugin.

I am able to debug all the `.cs` files, but not the `.cshtml` file. The `.cshtml` file is marked as embedded resource that is not copied to output directory.

Whenever I set a break point in the `cshtml` file it looks like all the other until I start the debugging, then it says `"...No symbols have been loaded for this document"` when hovering on the breakpoint.

Should it be possible to debug a `.cshtml` file with Razor syntax in Visual Studio 2013?

Answer (score 0):

You cant debug the .Cshtml file which is marked as embedded resource.So you have to place the view under the view's folder or shared folder.You may test it by debug the existing plugin's view which is marked as embeded resource.